# WinUI 3 How to set Minimum Size of a Window

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, winui-3

So in UWP, we can use

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(500, 500));
```

but

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
```

returns null in WinUI 3.
Is there a way to set the minimum size for a window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended solution, [implemented on GitHub](https://github.com/WinUICommunity/SettingsUI/blob/ce6bd6a86c07170d2ffcaa5a80c7dc02a2ba5028/src/SettingsUI/Tools/Helpers/WindowHelper/WindowHelper.ReSizeWindow.cs), is to use P/Invoke to call [the window subclassing functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#subclassing-controls-using-comctl32dll-version-6) `SetWindowSubclass` and `DefSubclassProc`:

1. Write a static WndProc method that handles `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, then forwards any other window messages to the original WndProc, via `DefSubclassProc` (or `CallWindowProc` in the examples), although note the [disadvantages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#disadvantages-of-the-old-subclassing-approach)).
2. Register your new WndProc via `SetWindowSubclass` (or `SetWindowLongPtr` in the examples).

This comes from [an issue on the XAML GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2945).

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825683/wm-getminmaxinfo-in-winui-3-with-c) and [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755645/how-can-i-add-a-minimum-size-in-winui-3) for more info.