# How can I add a minimum size in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, winui-3, winui

How can I set a minimum size for the window in WinUI 3?

#### Problem

[image: GIF Of The Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no **MinSize** or **MaxSize** properties yet on [the Window class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) in WinUI3.

A workaround is that using the [SetWindowSubclass function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) to hook WM_GETMINMAXINFO and set the min size.

Please check this Github link: [How to set minimum window size (Desktop)](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2945) which contains more discussion about this.

Comment: Are there any plans for this feature to be implemented in the future?

Comment: @TammyMo Please submit a feature request about this in the Github issues.