# WM_GETMINMAXINFO in WinUI 3 with C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

#### Problem

Since **WinUI 3** currently has no function to set the minimum size, I have to use `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`.

#### Question

How can I specify `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` minimum or maximum window size with **C#** in a **WinUI 3** project?

Do I need to set it in the `App` class or `MainWindow` class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's related to the window https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2945

Comment: Hey, thanks for this suggestion. I already saw this answer, this solution seems to have problems with my project. Is there not another possibility?

Comment: You should expose what you did and explain what are your issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this](https://github.com/WinUICommunity/SettingsUI/blob/ce6bd6a86c07170d2ffcaa5a80c7dc02a2ba5028/src/SettingsUI/Tools/Helpers/WindowHelper/WindowHelper.ReSizeWindow.cs) example on GitHub.

Here is a full example of a WinUI 3 window with a specified min and max width and height:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    private static WinProc newWndProc = null;
    private static IntPtr oldWndProc = IntPtr.Zero;
    private delegate IntPtr WinProc(IntPtr hWnd, WindowMessage Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    internal static extern int GetDpiForWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, WinProc newProc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, WinProc newProc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, WindowMessage Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static int MinWindowWidth { get; set; } = 900;
    public static int MaxWindowWidth { get; set; } = 1800;
    public static int MinWindowHeight { get; set; } = 600;
    public static int MaxWindowHeight { get; set; } = 1600;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        RegisterWindowMinMax(this);
    }

    private static void RegisterWindowMinMax(Window window)
    {
        var hwnd = GetWindowHandleForCurrentWindow(window);

        newWndProc = new WinProc(WndProc);
        oldWndProc = SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, WindowLongIndexFlags.GWL_WNDPROC, newWndProc);
    }

    private static IntPtr GetWindowHandleForCurrentWindow(object target) =>
        WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(target);

    private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, WindowMessage Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        switch (Msg)
        {
            case WindowMessage.WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
                var dpi = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);
                var scalingFactor = (float)dpi / 96;

                var minMaxInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MINMAXINFO>(lParam);
                minMaxInfo.ptMinTrackSize.x = (int)(MinWindowWidth * scalingFactor);
                minMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize.x = (int)(MaxWindowWidth * scalingFactor);
                minMaxInfo.ptMinTrackSize.y = (int)(MinWindowHeight * scalingFactor);
                minMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize.y = (int)(MaxWindowHeight * scalingFactor);

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(minMaxInfo, lParam, true);
                break;

        }
        return CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, WindowLongIndexFlags nIndex, WinProc newProc)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
            return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, newProc);
        else
            return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, newProc));
    }

    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MINMAXINFO
    {
        public POINT ptReserved;
        public POINT ptMaxSize;
        public POINT ptMaxPosition;
        public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
        public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum WindowLongIndexFlags : int
    {
        GWL_WNDPROC = -4,
    }

    private enum WindowMessage : int
    {
        WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x0024,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I specify WM_GETMINMAXINFO minimum or maximum window size with C# in a WinUI 3 project?

There is a way that detect current appwindow's real time size in [`Changed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.changed?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) method, and if the size is small or large then specific size you could call [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow.resize?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-windowing-appwindow-resize(windows-graphics-sizeint32)) method to set avaiable size. And here is [documet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/windowing/windowing-overview#code-example) that how to get appwindow.